# Issue using Pickadate.js - Not showing well

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to use pickadate.js but it does not show well on my page :
[image]

Here is my javascript files inclusion :

```
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery.min.js'/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js'/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/pickadate/picker.js'/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/pickadate/picker.date.js'/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/pickadate/legacy.js'/>"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js'/>"></script>
```

And in my jsp page :

```
$("#releaseDate").pickadate();
```

I have 0 javascript errors.

And the css inclusions :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/bootstrap.css'/>" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/style.css'/>" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/pickadate/classic.css'/>" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/pickadate/classic.date.css'/>" />
```

Thanks you !

Comment: Did you include the CSS file too?

Comment: Yes, I'm edditing my post right now sorry :)

Comment: Strange, all I can imagine is that you have something in your non-pickadate CSS files that's over-riding some styling- have you tried inspecting the problematic elements in Chrome/Firefox and seeing if anything coming from pickadate is being written over by style.css? Are there any `!important`s in there?

Comment: You were right!
It appeared my css were.. not well copied in my disk and part of the file were missing.. I don't know really why.

Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: Odd! Well, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as  Matt Fletcher said, it was a CSS problem. I did not saw this fact because one of my css file (date.time.css) had not been copied properly, and clases were missing !